# Is there any certification for java tool

Tags: java, windows, certificate

I am developing my own tool in java, is there any certification process required to standardize my tool?. so that I can release the tool to customers. like:usb driver certification

Comment: What does your tool do? There's no general certification process for Java programs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no certification for what you need.
What you can do is [sign your application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) using [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) with a trusted certificate.